# For loop is not being executed when I add an inner loop

Tags: swift, control-flow

I must have a fundamental misunderstanding of how flow control works in Swift, because this doesn't make any sense to me.

```
//objects is of type [AnyObject]?
for obj in objects!{
    let colors = obj.valueForKey("colors") as? NSMutableArray
    if colors != nil{
        for i in 0...colors!.count{
            if colors![i] as? String != nil{
                colors![i] = (colors![i] as! String).capitalizedString
            }
        }
        obj.setValue(colors, forKey: "colors")
     }
     obj.save()
 }//end for
```

When I remove the inner for loop, the outer one works normally, but when I add the inner loop, it never gets past the first iteration of the outer loop. There are no crashes or anything - everything else just resumes normally.

I'm not understanding why this is happening. Am I just being dense and missing something obvious?

Alternatively, I could probably just write a map function to capitalize the strings in my array, but I want to understand why this isn't working.

Comment: Can you give example input with unexpected behavior?

Comment: You say there is no crash but there is obvious error in `0...colors!.count` which has to end in a crash. Your answer suggests fixing that solves that problem so I am pretty sure there *was* a crash.

Comment: @Sulthan I thought so, too... but it seems to have worked in playground - until I noticed that I was using Swift Arrays and not NSMutableArray - so the loop was never executed (colors = nil). So yes, it's obviously wrong. :)

Comment: Considering the fix that you mention in your answer, it looks like the statement about there being "no crashes or anything" is not correct. Voting to close as "cannot reproduce".

Answer (score 1):

A simple example demonstrating the problem:

```
let array: NSMutableArray = ["a", "b", "c"]

for i in 0...array.count {
    print("Index: \(i)")
    print("Item: \(array[i])")
}
```

Prints:

```
Index: 0
Item: a
Index: 1
Item: b
Index: 2
Item: c
Index: 3
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'
```

Instead of `0...array.count` you should be using `0..<array.count`, as an even better alternatives, you should cast the array to a Swift array first and then use the more powerful `for-in` variants.

A simple example:

```
let array: NSMutableArray = ["a", "b", "c", 10, 20]

let colors = array as [AnyObject]
let newColors = colors.filter { $0 is String }
                      .map { ($0 as! String).capitalizedString }

print(newColors)
```

Of course, first you have to leave the concept of mutable arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used swift before but in terms of nested loops.. how long have you waited before determining that the outer loop won't make it past the first iteration?

For example, if you are looping over 10 million colors in the nested loop, that would take a while.

Alternatively, do you need to increment the iterator in the nested loop and it is currently running as an infinite loop?

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by changing the inner for loop from:

```
for i in 0...colors!.count{}
```

to

```
for i in 0...colors!.count - 1{}
```

But I have no idea why the former was causing the loop to break. Even when I removed everything from the inner loop, it still had the same issue. If anyone knows why this happened, please let me know.

Comment: A better fix would be `for i in 0..<colors.count` or using an actual Swift array instead of `NSMutableArray` which shouldn't be used at all in Swift.